# Rails ActionMailer copy email to sent folder SMTP ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, actionmailer

Hi I can send the email I want using the send mail function but No sent mail appears in the clients sent folder.

Do I have to manually copy the email to the sent folder somehow?  The config is below and works sending emails, just for reference

```
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'send.XXX.com',
      port:                 587,
      domain:               'XXX.com',
      user_name:            'X@XXX.com',
      password:             'XXX',
      authentication:       'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

How can I do this in Rails

**Update**

Can be done easily with IMAP, just make a new mail, Mail.new etc then

```
   target_mailbox = 'Inbox.Sent'
   imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.someserver.com")
   imap.authenticate(email_account.authentication, email_account.user_name, email_account.password)  
   imap.create(target_mailbox) unless imap.list('', target_mailbox)
   imap.append(target_mailbox, imap_sent_mail_copy.to_s)
   imap.logout
   imap.disconnect
```

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          target_mailbox = 'Inbox.Sent'
          imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.someserver.com")
          imap.authenticate(email_account.authentication, email_account.user_name, email_account.password)  
          imap.create(target_mailbox) unless imap.list('', target_mailbox)
          imap.append(target_mailbox, imap_sent_mail_copy.to_s)
          imap.logout
          imap.disconnect
```

where imap_sent_mail_copy.to_s is simply a Mail instance

```
imap_sent_mail_copy = Mail.new do
  to to_email_address
  from from
  subject subject
  message_id message_id
  if attachment_ids!=""
    docs = Document.where(id: attachment_ids)
    docs.each do |a|
      doc = Document.find_by_id(a)
        attachments["#{doc.name}.#{doc.file_ext}"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public#{doc.attachment_url}") if doc
    end
  end
  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' 
    body "#{message} #{signature}"
  end
end
```

Comment: where does `imap_sent_mail_copy` come from and how does this answer pertain to ActionMailer? how do I add this code to ApplicationMailer so that all sent emails get saved?

Comment: Its a Mail instance, see above in the answer

Comment: From your ActionMailer method, you can receive an object by mailObj = mail(...) then mailObj.body.encoded to assign on html_part do body thing.